# Tikzpicture horizontal tree - how to recombine daughters

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have a a horizontal tree representing a multi-period financial model. I want to have each parent converging into the same daughter as the parent's downside above them, and vice versa. I'm attached a copy of the code and a picture of how it stands, hopefully it's clear what I want to do.

For example in the attached picture I would like the two 9.54 nodes to be one node coming from the two previous parents...

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex}]
\node[square][label={[label distance=0.2cm]90:t=0}] {11.45}
    child {
    node[square] {19.08} 
        child {
        node[square] {29.54}     
            child {
            node[square] {40}        
                    }
            child {
            node[square] {20}         
                    }   
                }
        child {
        node[square] {9.54} 
            child {
            node[square] {20}        
                    }
            child {
            node[square] {20}         
                    }        
                }
        }
    child {
    node[square][label={[label distance=0.2cm]90:t=1}] {4.53}        
        child {
        node[square] {9.54} 
            child {
            node[square] {0}       
                    }
            child {
            node[square] {0}         
                    }       
                }
        child {
        node[square][label={[label distance=0.2cm]90:t=2}] {0}
            child {
            node[square] {0}        
                    }
            child {
            node[square][label={[label distance=0.2cm]90:t=3}] {0}         
                    }         
                }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome! What you want is not a tree and there is no easy way to do this. If you want, you can probably mangle something manually, but you can't do it in a way which fits the tree-structure. There are packages which let you do this, though. [genealogytree](http://ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree) can do this but is designed specifically for family trees. Or you can use the graph drawing facilities of TikZ, rather than the tree drawing ones.

Comment: For a one-off, I wouldn't bother with a graph. You can workaround it, although I'd try to avoid overtyping nodes as they end up looking bolder than the others. (I don't know if setting opacity to half for these would help.)

Comment: Please always post complete code. How is `square` defined? What packages do I need to compile this?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Well, I need three iterations of my answer to figured out, what is your problem ... Now I only reedit ma third solution and erase steps to it. Desired form is obtained with:

- selecting appropriate sibling and level distances
- in overlapping nodes I wrote content only in those of them, which are closer to beginning of picture code, the second ones I leave empty. Ba this is eliminated use of transparency in your question and own answer.

The MWE, which contain pointers to nodes in which a content are skipped, is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               ]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                   grow = right,
edge from parent/.style = {draw,-latex},
         label distance = 2mm,
      every node/.style = {minimum width=2em, inner sep=2pt},
         level distance = 31mm,
       sibling distance = 13mm,
                     ]
\node[label=90:{$t=0$}] {11.45}
    child {node {19.08}
        child {node {29.54}
            child {node {40}}
            child {node {20}}
                }
        child {node {}}%<---------------- already printed
            }
    child {node[label=90:{$t=1$}] {4.53}
        child {node {9.54}
            child {node {}}%<------------ already printed
            child {node {0}}
                }
        child {node[label=90:{$t=2$}] {0}
            child {node {}}%<------------ already printed
            child {node[label=90:{$t=3$}] {0}}
                }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cfr, you have right, I make it in one my other test files ... so I need some effort to clean up unnecessary packages ...

Comment: (+1) No sure `automata` is needed, is it?

Comment: @cfr, you are right again, it is not necessaty. I will erase it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much, bit silly of my not to realised I can just set sibling distance to constant. Have used opacity of 0.75 for two overlapping nodes and 0.5 for 3 overlapping nodes with a nice result.

[image: merged daughters]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex}, label distance = 0.2cm,
  level 1/.style = {level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=22mm},
  level 2/.style = {level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=22mm},
  level 3/.style = {level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=22mm},
  ]
  \node[label=90:{t=0}] {11.45}
  child {node {19.08}
    child {node {29.54}
      child {node {40}}
      child {node[opacity=.5] {20}}
    }
    child {node[opacity=.75] {9.54}
      child {node[opacity=.5] {20}}
      child {node[opacity=.5] {0}}
    }
  }
  child {node[label=90:{t=1}] {4.53}
    child {node[opacity=.75] {9.54}
      child {node[opacity=.5] {20}}
      child {node[opacity=.5] {0}}
    }
    child {node[label=90:{t=2}] {0}
      child {node[opacity=.5] {0}}
      child {node[label=90:{t=3}] {0}}
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: in your question you didn't tell, that you like to have merged the nodes in the last three level too. By the way, you still not define `square` ...

Comment: see addendum to my answer.

Comment: That still doesn't define `square` and will give errors if compiled.

Comment: square was defined earlier in my document, code was just for example.

Comment: A useful example works. It can be compiled. It is either a minimal ***working*** example (MWE) or (in the case of questions) it may be a minimal non-working example (MnWE) which reproduces the error which the question concerns. We realise you defined it somewhere. Our complaint is that you did not share that definition or, alternatively, remove usage of it from your code before posting. Examples you post should be copy-paste-compile and either work or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Even when I remove `square`, your code won't compile. Please test that the code you post compiles before posting it - especially in an answer which might reasonably be expected to solve a problem rather than creating one.

Comment: Thanks very much to Zarko providing excellent input and who obviously knows what can and can't be on with tikz.

Comment: @FeersumEndjinn, see if the last edit of my answer is what you looking for. In it I minimize code as much as it is possible. I hope that now it fulfill your expectation.

Comment: Very impressive